# ASP.NET MVC : how to find the view from a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know close to nothing about web programming.

I have been asked to add log statements to an existing system that uses ASP.NET MVC. I don't know the system. Other people developed it.

I have added the log statements to the controllers. I would like to test the log statements, but I don't know how to get to the views that call the controller methods.

That is, I think if I knew which views were calling what, then I could navigate my way when running the website to get to those views and thus, test the logging.
Usually with Visual Studio it gives that little intellisense line with references above the method, but not in this case. I guess it's some "magic" with web programming hehe. ;-)

So, how do I find out which view calls which controller method?

Comment: Name of the action on the controller matches the name of the view by convention. For example, the `Index` action on the `LogController` can be found at `~/Views/Log/Index.cshtml`.

Comment: This is the righ time to invest some time and learn the MVC basics https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/

Comment: Shelby is correct unless that Action is returning a View("viewName") that's different to the action name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is the other way around, the View is rendered by the Controller.

If a request (e.g. GET) is sent from the browser, MVC will first interrogate its *registered routes* to find out to which controller and action method this request should be routed to. See [ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs).
The routes are set up in `Global.asax.cs` in the `RegisterRoutes` method.

Normally there exists a default setup like this: `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"`.

This means if you e.g. browse to `http://myserver/Accounts/Edit/3`, this request will be routed to  `AccountsController.cs` where it will hit the `Edit(long id)` action method and pass `3` as `id`.

On the other hand, if you added a log statement to the `Delete(long id)` action in the `CustomersController.cs`, you can probably trigger this action by calling `http://myserver/Customers/Delete/1337`.

One thing to look out for are `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpDelete]` annotations above the action method. These define the HTTP Verb needed to reach this action. You can't reach a `[HttpPost]` action by sending a `GET` request.

At the end of the action methods you might find a line like `return View("Edit", viewModel);`. This tells MVC which CSHTML View file to use for rendering. The path to the CSHTML file will be looked up by convention, the first place MVC will look for is `Views\{controllerName}\Edit.cshtml`. But if Areas are set up, it will look for `{areaName}\Views\{controllerName}\Edit.cshtml` first.

Another thing you could search for in the code base are calls to `@Html.RenderAction` and `@Url.Action` which are used to call actions from a View. These also take `controllerName` and `actionName` as parameters, e.g. `@Url.Action("Accounts", "Edit", new { id = 3 })` will render an URL like `http://myserver/Accounts/Edit/3`.

Comment: This was very useful to me. Thank you! :-)